# remove lines between given range

Tags: variables, sed, numbers, line

I would like to remove lines given in the range of (NR==1, and a certain line number) which is assigned as a variable in sed.
For instance, I would like to remove line numbers from 1 to $ln . Here ln refers to variable name.
This is what I have done. But it does not. I really appreciate your help.

```
cat $FILENAME | awk ' /TotEng/{ln =FNR}END {print ln}
echo $ln
sed -e '1,{$ln}d' $FILENAME
```

How should I modify that script to delete lines between (1 and $ln)?

Comment: Are you trying to access `awk` variable in `sed` ? If so, You can't.

Comment: `awk -v num="$ln" 'NR>num' file` would print from line `$ln + 1` on.

Comment: I have tried it. But it gives an empty file. @fedorqui

Comment: We need a [mcve] to test. If you for example say `ln=5; seq 10 | awk -v num="$ln" 'NR > num'` works fine

Answer (score 2):

> to remove lines given in the range of (NR==1, and a certain line
>   number)

You can achieve it with single `sed` command:

```
sed '1,/TotEng/d' $FILENAME
```

---

> **1,/regexp/** form will match the beginning of its range and hence make the range span up to the *second* occurrence of the regular
>   expression.